# How can I shorten beautifully this C# code?

Tags: c#, oop, refactoring

I want to eliminate some duplicated code. Can anyone make this code shorter and better?

```
switch (now.site)
{

    case item.SITE.AMAZON:
        try
        {
            price = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"priceblock_ourprice\"]")).Text;
            fetched = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                price = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"priceblock_dealprice\"]")).Text;
                fetched = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                fetched = false;
            }
        }
        break;
    case item.SITE.ALI:
        try
        {
            price = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"j-sku-discount-price\"]")).Text;
            fetched = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                price = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"j-sku-price\"]")).Text;
                fetched = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                fetched = false;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't ever code by using exceptions. Exceptions are meant to be for exceptional circumstances. If you're trying to use them in ordinary code then they might as well be called `System.Ordinary`.

Comment: Is there any chance of a [mcve] so that we can offer a clean solution? I should be able to copy, paste, and compile your code at least.

Comment: Real web surfing causes many exceptional cases. I agree with you if C# selenium know element exists or clickable without exception.

Comment: Then catch the specific exception that is thrown and not every exception. It's a bad practice. Also then abstract away the code so that you only deal with it once.

Comment: Ok thanks its right to find specific exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're really trying to get a decimal value. Let's use this assumption and make a method that returns a `decimal?` to indicate success (i.e. a value) or failure (i.e. `null`).

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static decimal? FindDecimalMaybe(this IWebDriver driver, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            if (decimal.TryParse(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(path)).Text, out decimal result))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch { } // I hate this, but there doesn't seem to be a choice
        return null;
    }
}
```

The purpose of this method is to hide the unpleasant fact that the Selenium library appears to code by exception.

I've also created it as an extension method so that the call to `driver.FindElement` is replaced by something that looks familiar - `driver.FindDecimalMaybe`.

Now I take the same approach as Oliver with a dictionary:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string[]> __pricePaths = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
{
    { item.SITE.AMAZON, new [] { "//*[@id=\"priceblock_ourprice\"]", "//*[@id=\"priceblock_dealprice\"]" } },
    { item.SITE.ALI, new [] { "//*[@id=\"j-sku-discount-price\"]", "//*[@id=\"j-sku-price\"]" } },
};
```

Now it's trivial to get the values out:

```
decimal? price =
    __pricePaths[now.site]
        .Select(path => driver.FindDecimalMaybe(path))
        .Where(x => x.HasValue)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

If the `price` variable has a value then success, but if it is `null` then the call did not succeed.

Answer (score 7):

You could create a dictionary of available path strings. I don't know what the type of `site` is. I assume `string`

```
private static Dictionary<string, string[]> pricePaths = new Dictionary<string, string[]> {
   [item.SITE.AMAZON] = new string[] { "//*[@id=\"priceblock_ourprice\"]",
                                       "//*[@id=\"priceblock_dealprice\"]" },
   [item.SITE.ALI] = new string[] { "//*[@id=\"j-sku-discount-price\"]",
                                    "//*[@id=\"j-sku-price\"]" },
};
```

With this, you can write a more generic logic.

```
bool fetched = false;
if (pricePaths.TryGetValue(now.site, out string[] paths)) {
    foreach (string path in paths) {
        try {
            price = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(path)).Text;
            fetched = true;
            break;
        } catch {
        }
    }
}
```

It allows you to easily add new sites. The sites can have an arbitrary number of alternate paths.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot ..!!

Answer (score -1):

Here are some recommendations as to how you can beautify your code -

1. Declare constants for all XPath queries.
2. Declare a variable outside the switch statement to capture the price value based on your case statement.
3. Create a function with one try catch statements which accepts 2 xPath strings and an out parameter for Price and returns a boolean value to indicate if the query was successful.
4. Remove the try catch from under each case and call that function passing the correct xPath strings from the set of constants.

   ```
   const string priceblock_ourprice = "//*[@id=\"priceblock_ourprice\"]";
   const string priceblock_dealprice = "//*[@id=\"priceblock_dealprice\"]";
   const string j_sku_discount_price = "//*[@id=\"j-sku-discount-price\"]";
   const string j_sku_price = "//*[@id=\"j-sku-price\"]";

   public void YourPrimaryFunction
   {  
       decimal price;  
       switch (now.site)  
       {  
           case item.SITE.AMAZON:  
               fetched = FetchPrice(priceblock_ourprice, priceblock_dealprice, out price);
               break;  
           case item.SITE.ALI:  
               fetched = FetchPrice(j_sku_discount_price, j_sku_price, out price);
               break;
       }
   }

   private bool FetchPrice(string xPathPrim, string xPathFallBack, decimal out price)
   {
       try
       {
           price = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xPathPrim)).Text;
           return true;
       }
       catch
       {
           try
           {
               price = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xPathFallBack)).Text;
               return true;
           }
           catch
           {
               return false;
           }
       }
   }
   ```